# 100% success push, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an android/amazon-fireos cordova app using the pushy push service, the devices are bought by my company and the push needs to be 100% reliable. Now pushy is pretty good much better than GCM but I still have to ping the devices. Is there any way to get a push to have like ambulance level reliability? or any other suggestions to help with this task would be greatly appreciated. 
I'm willing to try anything, and usage/battery life on the device is irrelevant I can basically have full control of the system because they're not regular users.

Comment: You'll need to assemble your own 100% reliable Internet.

Comment: If a device is offline it is offline, there is no such thing as 100% reliable. You can add confirmation, so that you will know that a device received a notification, but again, those confirmations could also get lost.

Comment: lol I suppose in the respect I mean 100% reliable assuming their internet is constant. Not a whole lot I can do about that

Comment: I was mostly talking about androids tendency to shut everything off the longer its asleep, I already have a AlarmManager pinging the server as a keep alive along with the push, and an Ajax call that pings every minute. Kind of overkill seeming..

Comment: depending on the type of push required, you could send an sms in the cases where you do not receive a response from the mobile device so that the user can still get informed

Comment: Is there any realistic way to send say a JSON string in sms have the app recognize it, not display it and decode it? Im sure there is thats more of a hypothetical though. We're using amazon fire tablets with no cell service

Comment: Ambulance-level reliability?! I'd probably aim for higher than that :( Push services often have delivery notifications, so you'd have a queue of messages to send, then a queue of messages to confirm once they're sent. You'll have to determine your requirements for what that means, e.g., timespan, etc.

Comment: Well the way I determine that they've sent is by making a full server->tablet->server loop. I set it at a TTL of 180, its kind of awesome I can basically record the latency of each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can never have 100% reliability in the real world.  Murphy's law take effect.  There are way too many things that will be outside of your control.

Long answer:
You need to ask yourself, what constitutes 100% reliability?  Is it that the message eventually gets there at some point in time or within a certain time limit?

The more constrained the situation, the easier it is to get closer to 100%.

For example, if we can assume that the device will always be turned on, plugged in, and never ever move, then it's a lot easier to ensure that things won't go wrong.

Take it out on a cellular network and have it move around, things are going to get a lot more dicey as your signal strength goes up and down due to things outside of your control.

When working with mobile devices, much like almost everything else in the real world, nothing is ever 100%.  Network congestion, latency, loss, the battery dies, etc, etc, etc...

For mobile networks, seasonal changes can affect your reception.  For example, the leaves on trees have a way of interfering with high frequency radio transmissions.  This is why connections have a tendency to be better during the fall and winter seasons.

Another example: your device happens to be connected to a tower that, as you turn the corner in your car, is now blocked by a tall building.  Your device will then try to jump to another tower, but your connection may drop if the other ones are too congested.

Edit:
Just saw your comment about not using cellular connections.  If that is the case, you won't be able to SMS messages since that is something that is carried by cellular connections.

If you need something super reliable, you should seriously consider not using wireless connectivity if you can avoid it.

If you can't, then you need to redesign your solution around the fact that wireless network connections can be very unreliable.

Comment: thanks for your response. That is the unfortunate part, I wish android had an "Android for Work" option for increased privileges or something.. Oh an 100% reliability to me is if the tablet is on at full power with full wifi, screen on or off and it gets the message